# AMP: How can I create sitemap

Tags: sitemap, amp-html

My site based on AMP ( Accelerated Mobile Pages ); How can I create sitemap files if I have pages used ONLY AMP. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check on this [tutorial](https://jaaadesign.nl/en/blog/amp-sitemap/). Be noted that AMP does not need a sitemap (HTML or XML) if the content is marked up correctly: engines know where AMP content is by this piece of code present in your regular pages: `<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html">`. You can also check this [link](https://amptemplates.com/downloads/amp-html-sitemap-plugin/) for more information and explanation. The sitemap is added to your website by simply using the customizable shortcode. `[amp-sitemap append='amp' heading='AMP Sitemap' max='5']`

Answer (score 1):

Sitemaps can point to any content, it is only by convention that they normally point to webpages, they can point to PDF files, Word Documents, html pages running AMP, etc!

Create your sitemap as normal and it will get picked up and indexed.

As abielita mentioned, if you also have standard HTML pages the preferred way is to have *them* in a sitemap and then use the `rel="amphtml"` link.